# Mule 3: Enabling Correlation IDs

Tags: mule

I'm upgrading a Mule 1.3 application to Mule 3.2.1.  One of the outbound-routers is seemingly configured to generate a Correlation ID if the Mule message doesn't already have one.  This is done with an attribute called `enableCorrelation`.

```
<mule-descriptor name="theName" implementation="org.mule.components.rest.RestServiceWrapper">
    <inbound-router ... />
    <outbound-router>
        <router className="org.mule.routing.outbound.OutboundPassThroughRouter" enableCorrelation="IF_NOT_SET">
            <endpoint address="vm://..." />
        </router>
    </outbound-router>
    <properties>
        <property name="serviceUrl" value="..." />
    </properties>
</mule-descriptor>
```

How can this functionality be translated over into the Mule 3 config file?  I don't see any sort of XML attributes related to correlation IDs in the Mule 3 tags.  Here is the Mule 3 flow I've created so far:

```
<flow name="theName">
    <inbound-endpoint ... />
    <http:rest-service-component serviceUrl="..." />
    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="..." />
</flow>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `enableCorrelation` flag is available in Mule 3:

- on all [legacy routers](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Outbound+Router+Configuration+Reference), like `pass-through-router`, whose usage is now discouraged,
- on a few [routing message processors](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Routing+Message+Processors), like `collection-splitter`, where it is needed.

I'm afraid you'll have to create a custom transformer to simulate this behavior outside of using one of the above.

Comment: David thanks.  I can't seem to use the "pass-through-router" element without getting an XML validation error.  I tried wrapping it around and putting it inside the `outbound-endpoint` element but neither worked.  Is there a namespace I have to include?  Some examples I see show it being used with a `service`...do I have to use `service` instead of `flow`?

Comment: That is correct, legacy routers can only be used with the `service` construct, which you should not be using anymore as it will go away in a future major release of Mule.

Comment: So I guess that means I should create a custom transformer. :(  Do I even *need* to enable correlation?  Are correlation IDs added to all Mule messages by default?

Comment: Correlation is only *needed* for certain kind of routing operations, like splitting. Unless your app has special requirements on top of that, no, you do not need to worry about correlation ID. And no, Mule doesn't create a correlation ID by default, each message has a unique ID by default. Some transports do set the correlation ID on messages they create (like JMS) when it matches a low level concept (like JMSCorrelationID header), but most transport don't.

Comment: My flow uses Quartz to invoke itself on a regular basis.  The flow makes an HTTP request, transforms the HTTP response (I think it's XML) from a byte array to a String, then sends the String to someone in an email.  When a message is routed to a `smtp:outbound-endpoint`, is it just the message body that's included in the email body, or are other aspects of the Mule message include in the body as well (such as inbound properties)?

Comment: Do you know if `smtp:outbound-endpoint` includes the Correlation ID in the email message in any way?

Comment: The default outbound transformer (`ObjectToMimeMessage`) uses the current payload and the optional attachments to create the email message body parts. It is possible to define custom SMTP headers at SMTP connector level and with an outbound header named `customHeaders`. If there are attachments, outbound headers named `{attachment_name}Headers` are used as additional body part headers. So, by default, the correlation ID shouldn't be propagated. Log DEBUG `org.mule.transport.email.transformers.ObjectToMimeMessage` to see actual headers created.